# Hardware components for cancer detection using computer vision

Tags: hardware

Can anyone please tell me what are hardware components mentioned [in this project?](https://devmesh.intel.com/projects/invasive-ductal-carcinoma-idc-classification-using-computer-vision-iot#about-section)

I can see a total of three hardware components. But I am not able to recognize what are those.

Comment: The word "hardware" and the word "component" is mentioned each once in the linked article in the general blurb at the bottom of the page i.e. their occurrence does not tally with something used in the project. You should be much clearer about what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To create the IDC classifier, I use the Intel AI DevCloud to train the neural network, an Intel Movidius for carrying out inference on the edge, and Intel UP2 to serve the trained model making it accessible via an API, and an IoT connected alarm system built using a Raspberry Pi that will demonstrate the potential of using the Internet of Things via the IoT JumpWay combined with AI to create intelligent, automated medical systems.

[Intel AI DevCloud](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/devcloud/overview.html)
[Intel Movidius](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/processors/movidius-vpu.html)
[UP2](https://up-board.org/)
[Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)
[IOT Jumpway](https://iotjumpway.github.io/Intel-Examples/)

Comment: These aren't "components" as expected at this Electrical Engineering site. These are sub systems. And the _use_ of electronics is explicitly off-topic here.